# PHP - Mostrando erros ao fazer submit.

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ao mostrar mensagem de sucesso após fazer alteração de senha, mostra esses erros.
[image: Print dos erros]

------- Esse é o action usado para fazer alteração da senha ----------
[image: Action para alteração de senha]

OBS: Os erros mostrados, são referentes à outras actions de outros formulários.

[image: Essa é a página onde eu chamo as actions]

Comment: variável não inicializada, exemplo, na editar faça assim : `if(isset($_POST['alterar_senha'])){`

Comment: A propósito, leia este post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Poxa, era esse o problema mesmo!! Muito Obrigada e desculpe por postar prints ao invés do código, é porque como sou novata por aqui, ainda estou aprendendo a postar rsrs.